# I am trying to list specific files in a directory and output them as a variable to a batch script I have already

Tags: batch-processing

I found a script which will defrag then shrink vhd files. I added a variable to prompt for the vhd I want to shrink and it works great but it's quite time consuming so I'd like to automate the variable so that it selects all the vhds from the directory and loops through shrinking them all. An added bonus would be to skip files in use so that the script doesn't fail.

I can list the files with

```
forfiles /p c:\temp /m *.vhdx
```

I can't work out how to output the above as a variable to allow me to automate the variable prompt I've added to the script below

```
set /p vhd="Enter full VHD filename including extension: "
(echo select vdisk file="D:\User_Profile_disks\%VHD%"
echo attach vdisk
)  | diskpart

defrag E: /u

(echo select vdisk file="D:\User_Profile_disks\%VHD%"
echo detach vdisk
echo compact vdisk
)  | diskpart
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working in Powershell. Script needs to be placed in same directory as the VHDs

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\User_Profile_disks" -Filter *.vhdx |
Foreach-Object {
    $vhd = Get-Item $_.Name
    $path = "$vhd"

@"
select vdisk file=$path
attach vdisk
"@ | diskpart

defrag E: /u

@"
select vdisk file=$path
detach vdisk
compact vdisk
"@ | diskpart
}
```